# I am trying to import keras using tensorflow on python 3.11.6

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keras

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

I keep receiving this errors

```
Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved
Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved
Import "tensorflow.keras.optimizers" could not be resolved
Import "tensorflow.keras.utils" could not be resolved
Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved
```

Appreciate your help everyone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! However, could you please provide more details about your current setup such as ide, environment, tensorflow version etc? Otherwise, we cannot help you.

Comment: Did you install the *tensorflow* package? `Ctrl+Shift+P --> Python: Select Interpreter` to select the correct interpreter.